# How to split a python list by comma

Tags: python, list

I have a list similar to:

```
industries_list = ["Computers, Internet","Photography, Tourism","Motoring, Manufacturing"]
```

How can I split this list so that the output would be something like:

```
industries_list = [["Computers","Internet"],["Photography","Tourism"],["Motoring","Manufacturing"]]
```

I have tried converting it to string, split it by comma and then put it back into a list, but that didn't give my the results I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the answers, all of you answers works `:)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using List Comprehension:

```
>>> industries_list = ["Computers, Internet","Photography, Tourism","Motoring, Manufacturing"]
>>> [s.split(',') for s in industries_list]
[['Computers', ' Internet'], ['Photography', ' Tourism'], ['Motoring', ' Manufacturing']]
```

And to remove the white-space:

```
>>> from string import strip
>>> [map(strip, s.split(',')) for s in industries_list]
[['Computers', 'Internet'], ['Photography', 'Tourism'], ['Motoring', 'Manufacturing']]
```

You could also use pure list-comprehension (embedded list comprehension):

```
>>> [[w.strip() for w in s.split(',')] for s in industries_list]
[['Computers', 'Internet'], ['Photography', 'Tourism'], ['Motoring', 'Manufacturing']]
```

Comment: If you are using `map()`, do know it won't work correctly on Python 3, and I'd use `map(str.strip, s.split(','))` instead of importing.

Answer (score 3):

Use `.split` on the string class:

```
>>> industries_list=["Computers, Internet","Photography, Tourism","Motoring, Manufacturing"]
>>> [var.split(',') for var in industries_list]
[['Computers', ' Internet'], ['Photography', ' Tourism'], ['Motoring', ' Manufacturing']]
```

If you'd like no spaces:

```
>>> [[s.strip() for s in var.split(',')] for var in industries_list]
[['Computers', 'Internet'], ['Photography', 'Tourism'], ['Motoring', 'Manufacturing']]
```

[Live demo.](http://pythonfiddle.com/stripping-and-splitting-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

Split each value by `','` in a list comprehension:

```
industries_list = [s.split(',') for s in industries_list]
```

You may want to strip away the extra spaces around the results:

```
industries_list = [[w.strip() for w in s.split(',')] for s in industries_list]
```

Demo:

```
>>> industries_list = ["Computers, Internet","Photography, Tourism","Motoring, Manufacturing"]
>>> [s.split(',') for s in industries_list]
[['Computers', ' Internet'], ['Photography', ' Tourism'], ['Motoring', ' Manufacturing']]
>>> [[w.strip() for w in s.split(',')] for s in industries_list]
[['Computers', 'Internet'], ['Photography', 'Tourism'], ['Motoring', 'Manufacturing']]
```